# How to get path for content file on Service Fabric application

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Currently, in my Service Fabric App,I am using content file as embedded resource and accessing it as follows

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("C:\src\MyProj\Content.chtml")).
```

However, problem with this is approach is that any change to content file will require full deployment and not just content modification.

What is the best/recommended way to use content with SF app?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not just content modification"? What are you trying to do/avoid? Pretty much you'll always have to do some sort of deployment to get the changes pushed out and running in the cluster.

Comment: Embedding resources in your assembly means you need to reload the assembly, which means restarting the service. Use data packages instead (see Loek's answer).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the data package for this. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-model#package-an-application

Comment: Would that not still require a redeployment of the application package in order to update the content files in the Data folder on each replica/instance?

Comment: Every package is individually versionable and deployable.You can do differential upgrades to deploy specific packages. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-advanced#upgrade-with-a-diff-package

Comment: Yes, that helps reducing the deployment time, but it is still a deployment, I think the OP was looking for a way to just modify the content that each service uses.

Comment: Data packages are designed specifically for this scenario, yes. You do have to do an application upgrade to change the content, but you can do a data-package-only upgrade which will not restart your service.

Comment: I don't think your link is specific enough to answer this question.